# Show content from other website and track the URL

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, jsf-2, primefaces

On my JSF page I am trying to show some other website in an iframe and show its URL. I understand now that for security reasons I can only access the URL of the iframe if it is showing some site of my domain. So, I've found that problem a lot of times in the internet, but I couldn't find any solution. I don't want to read the content of the iframe, but only the URL.

Is there any solution for this requirement? Using an alternative to iframes? Frameset, browser in browser? Popup?

Comment: It may help if you explained **why** you need to display content from another site (and its URL). What kind of content is it? Is it "your" content?

Comment: @RoToRa no it isn't my content. It's a game. I give the user a starting URL (e.g. in the iframe) and he has to find the correct url by surfing that other website. When he found it he shall click a button and the URL he found is validated. Of course i could also open a popup and he has to copy and paste the url he thinks is correct to my site...but usability!

Comment: So your site is a game, where people have to find a specific page on the web and you need the URL to "prove" that they found it? I don't think there is any way other than let the users surf in a separate window and copy and paste the URL to your site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the iframe option, I would test to see if the innerhtml of the iframe matches that of the website they are meant to reach. The innerhtml in webkit does seem to change as the user browses.
The only alternative I can think of is http proxying the web sites, changing the links to refer to your proxy, then telling them they win when the requested proxy URL matches that of the destination.

Comment: `innerHTML` is subject to the same security rules as the URL of an IFrame showing content from another domain, so you can access it either.